# Variables in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I'm trying to create a self incrementing value in my database the increases value after there has been a gap in time greater than a second. The Stream Analytics is currently sending data from an event hub to the different tables in a SQL Database so I just need to be able to store a single value so if there's no gap it stores the variable but if there is a gap its variable+1.

From what I've seen there is another question on here asking about variables but it has no responses and at this point it's becoming a real roadblock.

I've tried the normal way of declaring a variable in SQL:

```
DECLARE @New_Test_Number AS INT

IF DatabaseInputTestNumber IS NULL
    SET @New_Test_Number = 1;
ELSE
    IF DATEDIFF(SECOND,LAG(Time),Time) > 1
        SET @New_Test_Number = DatabaseInputTestNumber + 1;
    ELSE
        SET @New_Test_Number = DatabaseInputTestNumber;
```

Where *DatabaseInputTestNumber* is read from the database and *New_Test_Number* is my variable.

To clarify, the data comes from an event hub to stream analytics and then to an SQL database. The same database that stores the current test number.

Answer (score 0):

I try to replicate the issue in my environment with below sample data

[image]

Using below code:

```
DECLARE @New_Test_Number INT;
IF DatabaseInputTestNumber IS  NULL
   SET @New_Test_Number =  1;
ELSE

   IF  DATEDIFF(second, (SELECT  LAG(Time) OVER (ORDER BY  time) FROM  data), GETDATE()) >  1
        SET @New_Test_Number = DatabaseInputTestNumber +  1; 
   ELSE
    SET @New_Test_Number = DatabaseInputTestNumber;
```

I Got below error:

[image]

I tried with below code to resolve the issue:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseInputTestNumber INT;
DECLARE @New_Test_Number INT;
SELECT @DatabaseInputTestNumber = DatabaseInputTestNumber FROM  data;

IF @DatabaseInputTestNumber IS  NULL
   SET @New_Test_Number =  1;
ELSE
   IF  DATEDIFF(second, (SELECT  LAG(Time) OVER (ORDER BY  time) FROM  data), GETDATE()) >  1
     SET @New_Test_Number = @DatabaseInputTestNumber +  1;
   ELSE
     SET @New_Test_Number = @DatabaseInputTestNumber;
UPDATE  data
SET DatabaseInputTestNumber = @New_Test_Number;
SELECT  *  from  data
```

The data updated successfully:

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something but I still get "Unsupported statement: 'DECLARE'". This is in stream analytics right? I'll clarify some details in the question.